# installing Matplotlib on macbook pro 10.13.6

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to install Matplotlib on my macbook 10.13.6 in terminal with python terminal activated.

I have entered command

$ python -m pip install --user matplotlib

I keep getting a syntax error.  I have tried to remove the "--user" portion in the command line and still get a syntax error. Since I am entering in the python terminal window I removed the "$ python" and still got the syntax error. I also triend with python3 and still same syntax error.

Comment: Could you please attach the entire error?

Comment: I'd recommend using the anaconda distribution, which comes with many precompiled packages, including matplotlib. https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

Comment: I have tried in the command line:

Comment: I have tried: $ -m install —user matplotlib AND -m install —user install matplotlib AND -m install matplotlib and the syntax error points at $ AND second “l” in install the other times with SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I will try to figure it out by downloading at anaconda.com